# Separate class for creating a set of objects from file?

Tags: ios, design-patterns

I'm creating an iPhone app while learning OOP. I have two classes named GUTimer and GUInterval. Instances of each need to be archived to a plist and unarchived separately when needed.
My question is, should I create one manager class that manages the loading and saving of both these objects types. Or should I create separate classes, one that manages the saving and loading of GUTimer instances and one that manages the saving and loading of GUInterval instances?
I'm still studying OOP and this is for my graded project so I just want to come up with the best solution possible. Any help would be appreciated.
THanks.

Comment: I think reading and writing should be in GUTimer and GUInterval, no  need to make extra classes, as all these are part of model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have your objects implement the NSCoding protocol and then use something like this to archive/unarchive them:

```
+ (NSObject *)readArchiveFile:(NSString *)inFileName
{
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectoryPath, inFileName];

    NSObject *returnObject = nil;
    if( [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath] )
    {

        returnObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
    }

    return returnObject;

}

+ (void)archiveFile:(NSString *)inFileName inObject:(NSObject *)inObject
{
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectoryPath, inFileName];
    BOOL didSucceed = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:inObject toFile:filePath];
    if( !didSucceed )
    {
        NSLog(@"File %@ write operation %@", inFileName, didSucceed ? @"success" : @"error" );
    }

}

+ (void)deleteFile:(NSString *)inFileName
{
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectoryPath, inFileName];
    NSError *error;
    if ( [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath] && [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] != YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't really have a right answer.  If you're learning OOP, then you'll soon figure that out.  Best advice I can give is to break your objects down into areas of functionality, and then size.  You want to avoid huge classes for the sake of readability, but beyond that, its basically up to your own preference.  If you can justify a particular design decision, then it will probably work for you.